# PHP Carbon take number of minutes & convert to days

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I am trying to convert a number on minutes into number of days using Carbon.

```
$minutes = 1400;
```

I want to do something like below (which of course, does not work):

```
Carbon->minutes($minutes)->days();
```

I cannot find an example of this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not tested, but a quick look at [the docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) suggests it might be aimed more at DateTime objects than differences in time, so you could do something like this:

```
$now  = Carbon::now();
$days = $now->diffInDays($now->copy()->addMinutes($minutes));
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `CarbonInterval::minutes($minutes)->cascade();`?

Will cascade down your value and format it for humans.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert seconds to Jira style `1y 1m 1w 1h 1m 1s`:

```
class Translator implements TranslatorInterface, TranslatorBagInterface
{
    protected const TRANS = [
        'year'   => 'y',
        'month'  => 'm',
        'week'   => 'w',
        'day'    => 'd',
        'hour'   => 'h',
        'minute' => 'm',
        'second' => 's',
    ];

    public function trans(string $id, array $parameters = [], string $domain = null, string $locale = null)
    {
        return $parameters[':count'].self::TRANS[$id];
    }

    public function getCatalogue(string $locale = null)
    {
        return new \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue('pl_PL');
    }
}
```

```
$second = 1;
$minute = 60 * $second;
$hours  = 60 * $minute;
$day    = 24 * $hours;
$week   = 7  * $day;
$month  = 4  * $week;
$year   = 12 * $month;

$sum      = $second + $minute + $hours + $day + $week + $month + $year;
$interval = CarbonInterval::seconds($sum)->cascade();

$interval->setLocalTranslator(new Translator());
echo $interval->forHumans(); // 1y 1m 1w 1h 1m 1s
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert to years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds

```php
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
echo CarbonInterval::minutes(2212)->cascade()->forHumans();

//output  = 1 day 12 hours 52 minutes
```