# How to convert seconds into days hours minutes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to convert time interval in seconds into days hours minutes. I have tried this.

```
$value = '90060';
CarbonInterval::seconds($value)->forHumans();
```

I got the output

```
90060 seconds
```

My expected output is

```
1 day 1 hour 1 minute
```

How can I get the output using `Carbon` or `CarbonInterval`

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684969/php-carbon-take-number-of-minutes-convert-to-days

Comment: There's plenty of examples [in the documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval)

Comment: Check this http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/3172332/3918473

Comment: {{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',90060) }}, How about this ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I got a solution.

```
$value = '90060';
$dt = Carbon::now();
$days = $dt->diffInDays($dt->copy()->addSeconds($value));
$hours = $dt->diffInHours($dt->copy()->addSeconds($value)->subDays($days));
$minutes = $dt->diffInMinutes($dt->copy()->addSeconds($value)->subDays($days)->subHours($hours));
echo CarbonInterval::days($days)->hours($hours)->minutes($minutes)->forHumans();
```

**Updated Solution**

```
CarbonInterval::seconds(90060)->cascade()->forHumans();
```

Comment: One line with: `CarbonInterval::seconds(90060)->cascade();`

Comment: @godbout - Almost exactly what I was after! I used `CarbonInterval::seconds(90060)->cascade()->forHumans();` to get the nice formatting

Comment: glad it helps keeping your code clean and beautiful! ;)

Comment: Another solution:
$time = \Carbon\Carbon::now();  
echo $time->diffForHumans($time->copy()->addSeconds(120), true);

Comment: what if I don't want the seconds?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$init = 150065;
$day = floor($init / 86400);
$hours = floor(($init -($day*86400)) / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $init % 60;

echo "$day:$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

Comment: I used this solution, i needed the next output format: d:H:i:s, thank's

Comment: You can use php function gmdate

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);

Answer (score 2):

```
function dates($value) {
    $s = $ss%60;
    $m = floor(($value %3600)/60);
    $h = floor(($value %86400)/3600);
    $d = floor(($value %2592000)/86400);
    $M = floor($value /2592000);

    return "$M months, $d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with carbon:

```
$seconds = 90060;
$dt = Carbon::now()->addSecond($seconds);
$dt_old = Carbon::now();
$days = $dt->diffInDays($dt_old);
$dt = $dt->subDays($days);
$hours = $dt->diffInHours($dt_old);
$dt = $dt->subHours($hours);
$minutes = $dt->diffInMinutes($dt_old);

echo $days.'<br>';
echo $hours.'<br>';
echo $minutes.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value = '90060';

        $inAMinute = 60;
        $inAnHour = 60 * $secondsInAMinute;
        $inADay = 24 * $secondsInAnHour;

        $days = floor($value / $inADay);

        $hourSeconds = $value % $inADay;
        $hours = floor($hourSeconds / $inAnHour);

        // Extract minutes
        $minuteSeconds = $hourSeconds % $inAnHour;
        $minutes = floor($minuteSeconds / $inAMinute);


        $timeValues = [];
        $sections = [
            'day' => (int)$days,
            'hour' => (int)$hours,
            'minute' => (int)$minutes,

        ];

        foreach ($sections as $name => $value){
            if ($value > 0){
                $timeValues[] = $value. ' '.$name;
            }
        }

        $d= implode(' ', $timeValues);
        dd($d);
```