# Laravel Convert seconds into days hours and minutes

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, time, php-carbon

I have to implement some functionality using time calculation and my app has following type of code.

```
    date_default_timezone_set(auth()->user()->timezone);
                                        
        $t_now = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                                        
$t_allowed = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($shift_details->start_time) ;
                                        
 @endphp
    
 @php
$check = $t_allowed->diffForHumans($t_now);
                                       
  $search = 'after';
 $dff_min = $t_allowed->diffInSeconds($t_now, true);
                                        
 $init = $dff_min;
 $day = floor($init / 86400);
 $hours = floor(($init - $day * 86400) / 3600);
 $minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
 $seconds = $init % 60;
   $late_not_late = $hours . ' hours ' . $minutes . ' minutes ' . $seconds . ' seconds ';
```

first i want to confirm that  `$dff_min = $t_allowed->diffInSeconds($t_now, true);` is returning minutes or seconds? Acording to my knowledge `$dff_min` contain seconds
i know that hours could be calculate using `(init /3600)` but what is the meaning of following statement

```
$hours = floor(($init - $day * 86400) / 3600);
```

why developer subtracting `$day * 86400` from `$init`?

similary we also can calculate seconds by $init/60 since in one minute there are 60 seconds but
what is meaning of following line

```
$minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
```

and also why he is using Modulo here

```
$seconds = $init % 60;
```

Comment: there is in-built function in Laravel `CarbonInterval`, please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212433/3584881)

Comment: can you explain what and why is  happening in the $hours = floor(($init - $day * 86400) / 3600); ???

Answer (score 3):

`\Carbon\Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` will call twice the timelib and will loose the microseconds, just do `\Carbon\Carbon::now()` and you don't need to reinvent the wheel, you can get this exact string with:

```
$t_now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$t_allowed = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($shift_details->start_time);

$late_not_late = $t_allowed->diffForHumans($t_now, ['parts' => 3, 'syntax' => CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE]);
```

$late_not_late will contain `2 days 9 hours 20 minutes`